# SQLite query where issue

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables:

**Item**

- ID - primary key
- ItemName - String - Item Name
- ItemColour - String - Item colour
- ItemWeight - int - Item Weight

**Activity**

- ID - primary key
- ActivityName - String - Activity Name
- ItemID1 - Primary key of a row in `Item`
- ItemID2 - Primary key of a row in `Item`
- ItemID3 - Primary key of a row in `Item`

What I want to do is filter the `Activity` table dependant on `Item`, so for example return any `Activity` row where the `ItemColour` is `Red`, if either `ItemID1` or `ItemID2` or `ItemID3` is red, if that make sense.

What I'm struggling to do is get the `WHERE` part of the sql query working.

```
@"SELECT Activity.ID FROM Activity JOIN Item ON Item.ID = (Activity.ItemID1 OR Activity.ItemID2 OR Activity.ItemID3)"
```

The above returns all `Activity` rows as I'd expect however putting any `WHERE` on it stop it returning anything. How can I solve this?

If i have made a massive mistake in how im going about this then i'll happily change it.

Comment: Why are you potentially joining on three different columns?  Also, could you specify your DBMS?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Show the *actual* failing query and represenative data .. if the WHERE fail to match (but it returns rows with the JOIN), then the data is likely not as expected.

Comment: Also, pick MySQL *or* SQLite - not both. (I've removed both until you make up your mind.)

Comment: if i simply put where Item.ItemColour = 'Red' after the joins it returns nothing. if i remove all the joins apart from ItemID1 it returns data as id expect.

Comment: `ON Item.ID = (Activity.ItemID1 OR Activity.ItemID2 OR Activity.ItemID3)` Is this working in `SQLite`?

Comment: without the where yes it does, well data is returned, any where in the query it returns nothing.

Comment: As @Hamlet is suggesting, I don't think you can say `JOIN table ON col = (this OR that OR other)`, because that would imply the ORs are resolved before the `=` which doesn't make sense. I think you need `ON Item.ID = Activity.ItemID1 OR Item.ID = Activity.ItemID2 OR Item.ID = Activity.ItemID3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an `exists` clause:

```
select a.*
from activity a
where exists (select 1
              from item i
              where i.itemColor = 'Red' and
                    i.itemId in (a.itemId1, a.itemId2, a.itemId3)
             );
```

You can do this with your version of the query, but you might get duplicate rows if more than one of the three items is red:

```
SELECT a.ID
FROM Activity a JOIN
     Item i
     ON i.ID IN (a.ItemID1, a.ItemID2, a.ItemID3)
WHERE i.itemColor = 'Red';
```

Comment: I like your second query :)